# Difference between model classes and model instances in Django (documentation)

Tags: django, oop, django-models, django-2.2

I was reading Django Documentation and I got across this line.

```
     Managers are only accessible via model classes, not the model 
     instances.
```

What is the meaning of this line? I am not able to comprehend this. I know what are Model classes ( Represents the Table in Database if I am not wrong). Are the model instances same as what we call "objects" sometimes?

What does this line mean actually? IS this some OOP concept or just Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have a model X:

```
class X(models.Model):
    pass
```

Now if you want to access the Manager method, you need to access like this:

```
X.objects.all()
```

But the following line will not work:

```
> x = X()  # model instance
> x.save()
> x.objects  << will throw error
```

FYI: its django specific, not OOP.

Comment: 'MODEL' is the representation of an entire 'TABLE' of your database that has a 'MANAGER' and you can do operations (i.e query, crud) through this manager.

On the contrary,
'MODEL INSTANCE' is a single 'ROW' of an entire 'TABLE' of your database which undeniably does not contain any manager.

Hope this summarizes the concept.